# The implementation in source code of Backpropagation in TensorFlow (Conv2DBackpropFilter and Conv2DBackpropInput)

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Since two operations Conv2DBackpropFilter and Conv2DBackpropInput count most of the time for lots of applications(AlexNet/VGG/GAN/Inception, etc.), I am analyzing the complexity of these two operations (back-propagation) in TensorFlow and I found out that there are three implementation versions (custom, fast and slot) for Conv2DBackpropFilter (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_grad_filter_ops.cc ) and Conv2DBackpropInput (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_grad_input_ops.cc). While I profile, all computations are passed to "custom" version instead of "fast" or "slow" which directly calls Eigen function SpatialConvolutionBackwardInput to do that.

The issue is:
Conv2DBackpropFilter uses Eigen:“TensorMap.contract" to do the tensor contraction and Conv2DBackpropInput uses Eigen:"MatrixMap.transpose" to do the matrix transposition in the Compute() function. Beside these two functions, I didn't see any convolutional operations which are needed for back-propagation theoretically. Beside convolutions, what else would be run inside these two operations for back-propagation? Does anyone know how to analyze the computation complexity of "back propagation" operation in TensorFlow?

I am looking for any advise/suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the transposition and contraction, the gradient op for the filter and the gradient op for the input must transform their input using [`Im2Col`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4e75ae1f1e8c6479cfa86fde1a940453945e6671/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_grad_filter_ops.cc#L437) and [`Col2Im`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4e75ae1f1e8c6479cfa86fde1a940453945e6671/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_grad_input_ops.cc#L475) respectively. Approximately speaking, these transformations enable the convolution operation to be implemented using tensor contraction. For more information, see the CS231n page on [Convolutional Networks](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) (specifically, the paragraphs titled "Implementation as Matrix Multiplication" and "Backpropagation").

Comment: Thank you mrry. I understood this. But I am still confused that why Backpropagation in TensorFlow didn't do the convolution operation the compute function? Conv2DBackpropFilter and Conv2DBackpropInput do the backpropagaton, right? But in the compute() function inside these two operations, I only see the Im2Col and Col2Im, but I didn't see the convolution operation. Do you know why?

Comment: The convolution operation itself is implemented by doing `Im2Col` followed by a contraction. See [this blog post](https://petewarden.com/2015/04/20/why-gemm-is-at-the-heart-of-deep-learning/) for another discussion of how this is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

mrry, I got it. It means that Conv2D, Conv2DBackpropFilter and Conv2DBackpropInput use the same way by using "GEMM" to work for convolution by Im2Col/Col2Im. An other issue is that while I do the profile of GAN in TensorFlow, the execution time of Conv2DBackpropInput and Conv2DBackpropFilter are around 4-6 times slower than Conv2D with the **same input size**. Why?